# Динамическая подгрузка к классу библиотеки .jar

Tags: java

Мне нужно в java классе добавить библиотеку (.jar).
Как это сделать?

Comment: @White2Demon, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Канонический метод — используя [`URLClassLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html).

```
ClassLoader ldr = URLClassLoader.newInstance(
                      new URL[] { urlToYourJar },
                      ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
Class<?> cl = Class.forName("package.ClassName", true, ldr);
```

Теперь вы можете вызвать `newInstance()` или как-то по-другому воспользоваться рефлексией.

Comment: newInstance() что мне даст? Возможность обращаться к методам или что?

Comment: @White2Demon: Даёт объект, разумеется.